# Еж и еда

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Казалось бы, слова не особо похожи друг на друга, но мне почему-то кажется, что они родственные. Тем более, что в украинском языке они гораздо ближе: "ïжа" и "ïжак". Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Поверьте, далеко не каждая пара даже созвучных слов родственны.

Answer (score 2):

**ёж**

Происходит от праслав. формы *ezi̯o-, от которой в числе прочего произошли: укр. їж, їжак, сербск.-церк.-слав. ѥжь (греч. ἐχῖνος), болг. еж, сербохорв. jе̑ж (род. п. jе́жa), словенск. jéž, чешск. , словацк. jež, польск. jeż, в.-луж. jěž, н.-луж. jež. Родственно лит. ežỹs, латышск. ezis «eж» др.-в.-нем. igil, нов.-в.-нем. Igel «еж», арм. ozni, греч. ἐχῖνος «еж», фриг. ἔξις (вместо *ἔζις). Далее это слово связано с греч. ἔχις «змея», арм. iž «гадюка», т. е. «еж» = «относящейся к змее», возм., табуистическое название «пожиратель змей».

**еда**

Происходит от глагола есть, далее от праслав. формы *ědmь, от которой в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. ѣмь, ѣсти, русск. ем, есть, укр. їм, їсти, белор. ем, есць, болг. ям, сербохорв. jе̑м, jе̏сти, словенск. jė́m, jė́sti, чешск. jím, jíst, словацк. jem, jesť, польск. jem, jeść, в.-луж., н.-луж. jěm, jěsć. Праслав. *ědmь (инф.* ěsti); ср. лит. ė́du, ė́mi, ė́džiau, ė́sti «есть (о животных, скоте)», латышск. ę̄du, e^st, др.-прусск. īst «есть», др.-инд. ádmi, átti «есть», арм. utem «ем» (из и.-е. *ōd-), греч. ἔδω, ἔσθίω, ἔσθω, лат. edō, ēdī, готск. itan, прош. at, 1 л. мн. ч. ētum, др.-в.-нем. еʒʒan «есть».

**яд**

От праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. ядъ, ѣдъ «яд», ядьно «опухоль», ст.-слав. ІАдъ (ἰόν; Клоц., Супр.), русск. яд, ядовитый, укр. яд, также ïд, болг. яд(ъ́т) «яд, гнев, горе», сербохорв. jа̏д «скорбь, горе», словенск. jа̑d «гнев, яд», др.-чешск. jěd (род. п. jědu) «яд», чешск. jed, словацк. jed, польск. jаd «яд животных и растений», в.-луж. jěd «яд», н.-луж. jěd. Стар. этимология считает исходным *ēdu- и сближает это слово с и.-е. *еd- (см. еда́, ем), ср. лит. ė̃dis «еда, пища», др.-исл. át ср. р. «кушанье», норв.-датск. ааt «приманка для хищников». Соответственно этому толкованию здесь представлено эвфемистическое название яда – «кушанье»; ср. нем. Gift «яд» от gеbеn «давать», франц. роisоn «яд» из лат. pōtiōne(m) «питье». Другая гипотеза полагает исходным *oid-, слово сравнивается с греч. οἶδος «опухоль», οἰδάω «распухаю», др.-в.-нем. еiʒ «нарыв» или др.-исл. eitr ср. р. «яд, гнев», др.-в.-нем. еitаr «гной», латышск. idrа «гнилая сердцевина дерева». Менее вероятно толкование слав. jadъ как сложения *ē и *dō, т. е. якобы «то, что дано, принято». Следует считаться с возможностью, что и.-е. *ēdu и *oid- совпали в слав. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

Хочу обратить внимание, что еще от "есть" произошло слово "яство" и оно уж точно на ежа нисколечки не похожи.

Насчет украинского языка не в курсе.

Comment: От есть - еще и яд. Кстати, одинаковы ли корни _есть_ - кушать и _есть_ - существует? Кажется, какое-то из них писалось через ять?

Comment: Да, я тоже думаю, что "яд" от "еды". А касательно есть I и II, то они и в оригинале ([\*h₁ed-][1] vs [\*h₁es-][2]) были не очень отличны :-)

 [1]:http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%81ed-
 [2]:http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%81es-

Comment: >От есть - еще и яд. Кстати, одинаковы ли корни есть - кушать и есть - существует? Кажется, какое-то из них писалось через ять?
  
Есть (еду) писалось через ять. Отсюда, кстати, и рефлекс ï в украинском.